# Fastest way to remove elements

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, collections

```
private void removeUnwantedIds(List<Path> allIDs, Set<String> acceptedIds) {

//keep only the paths that contain string which are in acceptedIds

}
```

Hi I am using Java 1.7 and wanted to understand how I can remove some of the file path elements that are contained in `allIDs` collection. The `acceptedIds` are `String` of Ids. If a path contains an Id from the list of `acceptedId` set, it should `retain` it or else remove. What would be the most efficient way to remove the unwanted paths.

*e.g. Elements in `allIDs`*

src\test\resources\file\15\54\54_exampleFile.pdf

src\test\resources\file\15\1001\1001_exampleFile.pdf

*e.g. Elements in `acceptedIds`*

54

64

101

How can I remove `src\test\resources\file\15\1001\1001_exampleFile.pdf` from the `allIds` list

Comment: `allIDs.retainAll(acceptedIds);`?

Comment: @Kayaman allIDs should first be converted to a list of String

Comment: @Kayaman type doesn't match. Use CollectionUtils.select or guava Iterables.filter

Comment: @JEY can you demonstrate an example? I've edited the question to  include scenario and example elements.